# code runs, but says invalid

Tags: c, invalidation

When I run my program it asks for a command, when you type in a, b, or c it prompts you to give the letter based on you chose a value. Any other command listed displays statistics. My small issue is that when I type in a valid command, my "invalid command" warning pops up, even though it works

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
   double a = 0;
   double b = 0;
   double c = 0;
   double d = 0;
   double e = 0;
   double f = 0;
   double g = 0;
   double h = 0;
   double i = 0;

   char command = '\0';

   printf("\n      Welcome\n");
   printf("     Aquapodz Stress Analysis Program\n");
   printf("    ==================================\n");
   while (command != 'x');
   {
      printf("\n\n(a), (b), or (c), enter trial data for        vendor.\n(f)ail-rate,     (m)ean stress, (s)ummary, e(x)it\n");
      printf("Please enter a command");
      scanf("%c", &command);

      if (command == 'a')
      {
         printf("Please enter stress values (GPa) for this trial.");
         scanf("%lf", &a);
         scanf("%lf", &b);
         scanf("%lf", &c);
      }
      else if (command == 'b')
      {
         printf("Please enter stress values (GPa) for this trial.");
         scanf("%lf", &d);
         scanf("%lf", &e);
         scanf("%lf", &f);
      }
      else if (command == 'c')
      {
         printf("Please enter stress values (GPa) for this trial.");
         scanf("%lf", &g);
         scanf("%lf", &h);
         scanf("%lf", &i);
      }
      else if (command == 'f')
      {

         printf("Average failure rate:\nAzuview:%f\nBublon:%f    \nCryztal:%f\n",        a+b+c, d+e+f, g+h+i);
      }
      else if (command == 'm')
      {
         printf("Average mean stress:\nAzuview:%f\nBublon:%f\nCryztal:%f\n",         a+b+c/3, d+e+f/3, g+h+i/3);
      }
      else if (command == 's')
      {
         print("Total (pass / fail) so far:\nAzuview:%f(%f/0)\nBublon:%f(%f/0)        \nCryztal:%f(%f/0)\n", a+b+c, a+b+c, d+e+f, d+e+f, g+h+i, g+h+i);
      }
      else if (command == 'x')
      {

      }
      else
      {
         printf("Invalid Command! Please Try Again :)");
      }

   }
   printf("Goodbye, Please Come Again!");
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  scanf("%c", &command);
```

is the problem. You end up reading the newline character left over from the previous call to `scanf`. Use

```
  scanf(" %c", &command);
```

Answer (score 1):

When you enter in any value, there's also a newline character that gets fed in when you press return.  Since none of your `scanf` patterns match for the `\n`, it stays in the buffer and gets picked up on the next `scanf`

So instead of this:

```
scanf("%c", &command);
```

Do this:

```
scanf("%c\n", &command);
```

And do the same for anyplace else you use `scanf`.

Comment: That won't work if the newline left in the input stream is from `scanf("%lf", &i);`.

Comment: That's why I mentioned that a similar fix needs to happen in all `scanf` calls.